# Change of flexible array into pointer

Tags: c, misra, flexible-array-member

I am working to get rid of MISRA violations coming in my C code. It is violating **rule 18.7**.

```
struct abc {
  struct header;
  uint8_t data[]; /* Line 1 */
};
```

Here, Line 1 is causing the MISRA violations.

I tried to convert it into:

```
struct abc {
  struct header;
  uint8_t *data;
};
```

Can we do like the above or is it violating something ?

Comment: Since the MISRA rules are not FoC it would be helpful if you told us what rule 18.7 is.

Comment: Rule 18.7
Flexible array members shall not be declared.

Comment: Flexible array members are problematic because the compiler cannot know their actual sizes, yet it may treat them as if it does, in which case it will use the size of the base portion of the structure, excluding the flexible array member. That can cause bugs, since the wrong size is used. The proposed solutions to use `data[0]` or `data[1]` instead do not resolve that problem. If you know the maximum size of data and it is reasonable (not too much wasted space when it is not all used), then declaring the array with that size could be a solution.

Comment: The problem here is not “get rid of MISRA violations.” The actual problem is “Accomplish a task without MISRA violations.” The correct solution depends on what the task is. What was this structure supposed to be used for? Is it used for handling or managing existing data, and you have to fit it to the data? Or are you designing some new algorithm and can use any data structure that is suitable? What is the actual task to be performed?

Comment: @EricPostpischil - the problem is "accomplish a task without *unresolved* violations" - a violation may be accepted as is (Advisory Rules) or subject to a Deviation (Required Rules) - or change the source code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is semantically different and won't work even if it clears the violation.

The intent here is to create a structure that can act as a header for the contiguous data that follows it. So for example if you have:

```
struct Message
{
    struct abc info ;
    char data[128] ;
}  message ;
```

Such that `message.info.data` and `message.data` refer to the same thing and casting a `struct abc` to a `struct Message` allows a function to be defined for passing any object with a `struct abc` header.  Effectively supporting polymorphism in C.

Replacing it with:

```
struct abc 
{
  struct header;
  uint8_t* data;
};
```

is semantically different because the `data` member does not refer to the data contiguous with `header`.  The copy semantics also differ, and it is unlikely in the context of the code that uses the original structure that it will work as intended.

GCC supports the following syntax:

```
struct abc 
{
  struct header;
  uint8_t data[0] ;
} ;
```

but it is likely that is not MISRA compliant either.  A compliant solution is to have:

```
struct abc 
{
  struct header;
  uint8_t data[1] ;
} ;
```

But that inserts an extra character and any code that uses this as a header may need to accommodate that when accessing the data through the `data` member.

Comment: Although using `data[0]` or `data[1]` may satisfy the wording of MISRA and the automated checker, it would not satisfy the intent—it would still be a structure whose actual use with data of varying size differed from its declaration as a structure with fixed size, exposing it to the same problems as a flexible array member. One solution would be to declare the array with the maximum size to be handled, if it is known and reasonable. Otherwise, some other solution should be devised.

Comment: @EricPostpischil : yes, all that.  I was more concerned here that the semantics should not be changed by naively changing the structure.  To conform to the spirit rather than the rule is likely to require a more significant redesign affecting the wider code.  The use of a pointer would require allocating memory from a pool or heap and the consequent management of ownership, lifetime, and release.

Comment: `data[0]` isn't valid ISO C so it violates MISRA-C. `data[1]` is the "struct hack" and undefined behavior, so it also violates MISRA-C. The correct solution is to declare a fixed-size array.

Comment: @Lundin All true.  The data[1] itself is not non compliant; using it as a "struct hack" may well be.  My intent was not to provide a compliant solution, but to point out the semantic differences between them.  The problem is not really about this one structure member, since any compliant solution would require design and implementation changes elsewhere.  The original code semantically says "data follows", whereas the pointer member says "data is somewhere else", so location, validity, and consistency of that data needs to then be dealt with.

Answer (score 1):

All safety-related systems bans dynamic memory allocation, and therefore MISRA-C:2012 does so as well. This is the rationale for rule 18.7: flexible array members are closely associated with with dynamic allocation and therefore not allowed.

The reason why dynamic allocation is banned is that there can be no non-deterministic behavior in these kind of systems. In addition, it [doesn't make any sense](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171257/realloc-wasting-lots-of-space-in-my-mcu/171581#171581) to use dynamic allocation in microcontroller/RTOS applications.

You can swap the flexible array member for a pointer if it makes sense to your application. But if it is some manner of protocol or data structure header, you probably want a fixed-size array instead. (And mind struct padding: storing data communication protocols in structs can be problematic because of alignment and endianess.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, as it makes the structure size deterministic and static, but it also forces you to allocate then release the needed space for `data` with `malloc()` and `free()`, or explicitly make it point to some already available space somewhere, each time you instanciate the structure.

What you probably want to do here is to specify a definite length to your array. If however this structure is meant to actually describe the header of a data block, you may use `data[1]` then let your index exceed this value to access the rest (ISO C forbids 0-length arrays, though).

Comment: Although using `data[1]` may satisfy the wording of MISRA and the automated checker, it would not satisfy the intent—it would still be a structure whose actual use with data of varying size differed from its declaration as a structure with fixed size, exposing it to the same problems as a flexible array member. One solution would be to declare the array with the maximum size to be handled, if it is known and reasonable. Otherwise, some other solution should be devised.

Comment: This is what I meant by saying "_What you probably want to do here is to specify a definite length to your array_." Maybe I should have developed a bit…

Comment: You are not "forced" to use malloc in this case. That is one possibility, but the pointer may refer to any memory object. Default malloc implementations are typically non-deterministic. A fixed block memory allocator may be used, or even just a pointer to some object with ownership and management indicated in the header structure.

Comment: Once again, this is what I meant by "_ or explicitly make it point to some already available space somewhere_". And I believe we all agree on this too : this would make MISRA happy, but at the cost of something that is probably even more dangerous (non-allocated pointers, memory leaks and segfaults).