# gcc.exe warning cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef void SeqList;
typedef void SeqListNode;
typedef unsigned int TSeqListNode;

typedef unsigned int TSeqListNode;
typedef struct _tag_SeqList
{
    int capacity; 
    int length; 
    TSeqListNode *node;
}TSeqList;

SeqList * SeqList_Create(int capacity)
{
    TSeqList *ret = NULL;
    if(capacity>=0)
    {
        ret = (TSeqList *)malloc(sizeof(TSeqList) + sizeof(TSeqListNode)*capacity);
    }
    if(ret == NULL)
    {
        printf("malloc fail.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    ret->capacity = capacity;
    ret->length = 0;
    ret->node = (TSeqListNode*)(ret+1);
    return ret;
}

int SeqList_Insert(SeqList *list, SeqListNode *node, int pos)
{
    TSeqList *sList = (TSeqList*)list; 
    int ret = (sList != NULL);
    int i = 0;
    ret = ret && (sList->length+1 <= sList->capacity);
    ret = ret && (0 <= pos);
    if(ret)
    {
        if(pos >= sList->length)
        {
            pos = sList->length;
        }
        for(i=sList->length; i > pos; i--)
        {
            sList->node[i] = sList->node[i-1]; 
        }
        sList->node[i] = (TSeqListNode)node;
        sList->length++;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

```
D:\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -g D:\Cpp\DSA\test001.c -o D:\Cpp\test001.exe
D:\Cpp\test001.c: In function 'SeqList_Insert':
D:\Cpp\test001.c:56:26: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
         sList->node[i] = (TSeqListNode)node;
                          ^
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide more information, for example what line the error is referring to and what the intention of your code is. As it stands, the compiler warns you that you cast a pointer to an integer, which is true, since TSeqListNode is an integer in your case. What are you trying to do?

Comment: sList->node[i] = (TSeqListNode)node;    //  Type conversion

Comment: `node` is a `SeqListNode *`, and `sList->node[i]` is an unsigned int. What's not to understand about that warning?

Comment: How to resolve warnings   
    warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
         sList->node[i] = (TSeqListNode)node;

Comment: Well I can see how that error might be hard to comprehend for unexperienced C developers, so no problem with the question. But OP will need to talk to us, otherwise its a little hard to help. Simply "getting rid of the warnings" will not help you. Please provide information, what you are trying to do.

Comment: @linyb These typedefs void SeqList;
typedef void SeqListNode; are very silly typedefs.

Comment: Explain your intention and add example code that calls your functions. In `SeqList_Insert`, `node` is a pointer to a `SeqListNode`. It does not make sense to cast a `some_type *` to `some_type`. Your intention is not clear. Do you want to copy the value where the function argument `node` is pointing to? This would be something like `sList->node[i] = *node;`. It is a strange way to allocate the memory for a structure and an array inside the structure. If your compiler supports flexible array members, I suggest to use `TSeqListNode node[]`; instead of `TSeqListNode *node;` with pointer tricks.

Comment: Your usage of the `void` pointers here is more than questionable. You should get rid of that or tell us a good reason why you use `void` here.

Comment: @SupportUkraine `(ret+1)` is okay. It declares an array, not a list. The main problem is the `typedef` obfuscating the intent of the code.

Comment: @PhilMasteG Inexperienced C developers should not use casts _anywhere_. I'm pretty sure there's literally no existing scenario where they ever need to use casts. In some 99% of the cases, the presence of a cast in a beginner program means there's either a bug or code smell.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is already part of the ISO/IEC 9899:1999 C standard. It's called **flexible array member**. So no need for inventing your own code - just use what is already available.

Also notice that capacity and length are variables that can't be negative. So you should use an unsigned type. The common used type would be `size_t`.

So your code should be:

```
typedef struct _tag_SeqList
{
    size_t capacity; 
    size_t length; 
    TSeqListNode node[];  // Flexible array member
} TSeqList;
```

Now you can simply do:

```
ret = malloc(sizeof(TSeqList) + sizeof(TSeqListNode)*capacity);
             \--------------/   \----------------------------/
              Memory for the       Memory for the 'node' array
              struct, i.e for       with 'capacity' elements
              capacity and
              length
```

to allocate (no need for checking the value of `capacity` as it can't be negative).

And just use `node` as a normal array.

All the need for casts are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier versions of the C standard (C90) probably do necessitate casting. I think a placeholder data `(int *)(array + 1)` is entirely appropriate in some situations, assuming alignment is respected. Note that you might also make this design decision to comply with [MISRA C 2012 Rule 18.7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56088983/2472827). I have eliminated the obfuscating `typedef`s and renamed parts of it to reflect what it actually does more clearly. A cast to `void *` is basically turning off type-checking, (through a `typedef` or not,) and should be avoided where possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct IntArray {
    size_t capacity;
    size_t length;
    int *node;
};

/** @throws[malloc] */
static struct IntArray *IntArray_Create(const size_t capacity)
{
    struct IntArray *ret = NULL;
    ret = malloc(sizeof *ret + sizeof *ret->node * capacity);
    if(ret == NULL) return 0; /* Let the caller decide what to do. */
    ret->capacity = capacity;
    ret->length = 0;
    ret->node = (int *)(ret+1);
    return ret;
}

/** Returns false if the `array` is full or null. Clips `pos` to `array`. */
static int IntArray_Insert(struct IntArray *array, const int node, size_t pos)
{
    if(!array || array->length >= array->capacity) return 0;
    if(pos >= array->length) pos = array->length;
    /* Replaced looping over the array for performance. */
    memmove(array->node + pos + 1, array->node + pos, array->length - pos);
    array->length++;
    array->node[pos] = node;
    return 1;
}

#include <assert.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct IntArray *a;
    if(!(a = IntArray_Create(3))) { perror("fail"); return EXIT_FAILURE; };
    assert(IntArray_Insert(a, 1, 42));
    assert(IntArray_Insert(a, 3, 1));
    assert(IntArray_Insert(a, 2, 1));
    assert(!IntArray_Insert(a, 2, 1));
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

If you are targeting `C99` or later, the flexible array member may be useful for this exact reason. If this is part of a macro, the only `typedef` you really need is `typedef int ArrayType;`.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof *ret + sizeof *ret->node * capacity);` to allocate `capacity` * `int` and not `capacity` * `int *` ?

Comment: @YannDroneaud Good catch.